# Errors from avro.serde.schema - "CannotDetermineSchemaSentinel"

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

When running jobs on Hadoop (CDH4.6 and Hive 0.10), these errors showed up:
avro.serde.schema
{"type":"record","name":"CannotDetermineSchemaSentinel","namespace":"org.apache.hadoop.hive","fields":
[{"name":"ERROR_ERROR_ERROR_ERROR_ERROR_ERROR_ERROR","type":"string"},{"name":"Cannot_determine_schema","type":"string"},{"name":"check","type":"string"},
{"name":"schema","type":"string"},{"name":"url","type":"string"},{"name":"and","type":"string"},{"name":"literal","type":"string"}]}

What's the root cause, and how do I resolve them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This happens when Hive is unable to read or parse the avro schema you have given it. Check the avro.schema.url or avro.schema.literal property in your table; it is likely it is set incorrectly.